# Cobertura task is not getting included as part of gradle build

Tags: gradle, cobertura

I am doing a build using gradle. When I do a "gradle clean build" it executes all my test cases and build succeeds. When I do a gradle clean cobertura it generates my cobertura report. I want to integrate cobertura reports as part of gradle build. I tried in the below option in build.gradle, but it gives me an error.

```
build{

 dependsOn cobertura

}
```

Error that i got. Any thoughts on this?

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':build'.
> Cannot convert net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaExtension_Decorated@528e5e38 to a task.
The following types/formats are supported:
- A String or CharSequence task name or path
- A Task instance
- A Buildable instance
- A TaskDependency instance
- A Closure instance that returns any of the above types
- A Callable instance that returns any of the above types
- An Iterable, Collection, Map or array instance that contains any of the above types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cobertura is the name of the extension. The task to create the cobertura report is called `coberturaReport`.

So you have to do:

```
build.dependsOn coberturaReport
```